# imported tables from pdf in R

Tags: r

when i imported a table from pdf in R, i have 2 problems, this is my code:

```
library(datasets)
library(jsonlite)
library(remotes)
library(rJava)
library(devtools)
library(tabulizer)
library(tidyverse)
library(mongolite)


setwd("C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documentos/Bingo 202309/extraerfotos")
bingo = "2.pdf" #5 rows, 5 columns
mf = extract_tables(bingo, output = "data.frame") %>% as.data.frame()
```

the pdf file contain only the columns B I N G O, the first 5 columns was from the previous pdf imported. What i'm doing wrong, i just started using R lenguaje :(

Best regards

i got this:

```
   B  I     N  G  O B.1 I.1   N.1 G.1 O.1
1 11 23    44 50 72   1  16    36  56  70
2  9 25    40 60 74   9  30    34  46  73
3  5 22 BINGO 55 68  14  19 BINGO  53  75
4 12 26    35 59 69   7  17    31  48  64
5  1 24    38 48 63  11  29    32  52  62
```

when i need :

```
   B  I     N  G  O 
1  1  16    36  56  70
2  9  30    34  46  73
3  14 19 BINGO  53  75
4  7  17    31  48  64
5  11 29    32  52  62
```

Comment: I don't see obvious problems with the code. Is the PDF on a public site?

Comment: is a local file, in path "setwd("C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documentos/Bingo 202309/extraerfotos")". First i used "1.pdf" then "2.pdf"

Comment: can you give us the results of `str(mf)` please?

Comment: My point is this: how are we supposed to know anything about the PDF file? We don't know what it looks like, how it is structured internally, we know nothing. Further, PDF can be structured in ways that make scraping tables extremely difficult, it matters more how it is structured internally than how it looks on the rendered page. So even if you provide a picture of what that pdf page looks like, it still doesn't mean we can help much since we don't know how well it is extracted. `tabulizer` and `pdftools` are my go-to tools for this, and ... results always vary.

Comment: > str(df)
'data.frame': 5 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ B  : int  11 9 5 12 1
 $ I  : int  23 25 22 26 24
 $ N  : chr  "44" "40" "BINGO" "35" ...
 $ G  : int  50 60 55 59 48
 $ O  : int  72 74 68 69 63
 $ B.1: int  1 9 14 7 11
 $ I.1: int  16 30 19 17 29
 $ N.1: chr  "36" "34" "BINGO" "31" ...
 $ G.1: int  56 46 53 48 52
 $ O.1: int  70 73 75 64 62